# meanColor() get BGR simpleCV

Tags: python, simplecv

I know that 'meanColor()' prints the values of BGR, but how can I individually get those values?

For example:

```
img = "picture"

colors = img.meanColor()

print(colors)
```

And I get something like this `(30,10,40)`

Let say I want the 30.

How can I assign it on another variable?

Please explain your solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a tuple, so you can go like :

```
blue  = colors[0]
green = colors[1]
red   = colors[2]  
#or
b, g, r = colors
```

Comment: I thought about that, but didn't really try it. Thanks